# How to sort a 10G(or bigger) csv file according to the value of selected column(such as col 2) using spark

Tags: python, file, csv, apache-spark

Now I have a 10G csv file which contains over 500000000 lines. Now I just want to sort the whole file according to the value of the first column. Could anybody tell me how to handle Spark configuration?

Comment: Is it necessary that you use spark? You could do the same thing with some type of iterative sort looking at a line at a time. A bubble sort comes to mind for me, although I don't have the most formal knowledge as far as sorts go. You may also want to look at using a DB rather than a file with that much data.

Comment: It should be possible to sort such a file using regular old `sort` or any other standard tool.  A bigger question might be whether you're willing to migrate away from CSV for such a task.

Comment: Is distributed file system necessary?